# Strange Hadoop M/R Behavior with Iterable.toarray()

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

In a reducer I would like to use the Iterable from Hadoop in an array, so I did this:

```
    protected void reduce(Text arg0, Iterable<Text> arg1, Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
...
...
    Text[] res = Iterables.toArray(arg1, Text.class);
```

then I was looping on that array with something like this:

```
for( int i=0;i<res.length;++i){...
```

after this, each element in the array are equal to the last. It seems to me that the Iterable passed to reducer by Hadoop contains always the same element that is update at each Next. As a result, calling res.length consume the iterator, and all elements in the returned arrays are equal.
Is this a desired/expected behavior? Does'nt it violate the way an iterator should be implemented?

Comment: what is arg1 in first snippet?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker sorry for being unclear, I extended the question.